# How do I get a Font from a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control a font can be set by referring Font by it's family name. How do I do something similar in code?

```
 <asp:Chart runat="server">
     <legends>
         <asp:Legend Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Bold"/>
     </legends>
 </asp:Chart>
```

How can I do something similar in the codebehind?

```
chart.Legends[0].Font = Font.???("Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Bold")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [one of the constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.font%28VS.100%29.aspx) on the `System.Drawing.Font` class:

```
chart.Legends[0].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 
                                 8.25,
                                 FontStyle.Bold);
```

Make sure to include `System.Drawing` to get easy access to all the related items (`FontFamily`, `FontStyle`, etc).

Comment: +1 But I prefer: 
new Font(new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS"), 8.25, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.BlinkText);

Comment: @Chris Ballance: -100 million for BlinkText. +1 for Comic Sans.

Comment: This will work, but it doesn't answer the question exactly, I would have thought maybe there was something in the framework which will consume the entire string and parse it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to parse it, assuming it always came in in that form:

```
string[] fontStrings = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt, style=Bold".Split(',');
fontStrings[1] = fontStrings[1].Replace("pt", "");
fontStrings[2] = fontStrings[2].Replace("style=", "");
var font = new System.Drawing.Font(
  fontStrings[0],
  float.Parse(fontStrings[1]),
  ((FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), fontStrings[2]))
);
```

**EDIT:** Ah, I did it the hard way. If it's not dynamic, the other answers are signficantly nicer than my string-munging. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following overload of the [System.Drawing.Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zet4c3fa.aspx) constructor:

```
chart.Legends[0].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25, FontStyle.Bold);
```